# How do you combine multiple expected values into 1 value?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let's say you have data with revenue from a car wash. You gain enough data to come up with expected values of revenue based on the color of the car and the style (coupe, sedan, or hatchback). That makes six separate expected values.

How do you combine expected values from these individual attributes into a single expected value? Is it simple addition?

Comment: You likely are referring to *conditional* expectations.  You're right that addition is incorrect.  After all, by simply collecting trivial information about each car--each of the digits of its VIN, for instance--you could obtain dozens or hundreds of "expected values," all of them close to the average revenue per car. Adding them would give you an "expected value" of tens or hundreds times the typical revenue.  If a little data collection always reaped such rewards, many more people would be scientists :-).  What you need is called [tag:multiple-regression].

Comment: @whuber please consider converting that to an answer.

Comment: @Glen_b I cannot answer it generally and succinctly--except by saying "in general you cannot"--without knowing what these "expected values" actually represent or how they are estimated. One can imagine pricing schemes where the revenues *can* be computed from such partial information.

Comment: @whuber To the extent that it can be answered in a reasonably brief answer I believe your comment covers the most salient points (particularly the guidance toward multiple regression, which I think is a suitable way to guide the OP -- toward widely used and useful but not completely general solutions). I don't even think a completely general answer should be attempted. What concerns me is you said about all there is to say in a good two paragraph answer and people may be discouraged from attempting an answer that doesn't add much to that, leaving us with more open but "unanswered" questions.

Answer (score 1):

To get the total revenue, you add up the revenue from your datasheet. That's all. If you want to predict the revenue based on an imaginary population of cars, with a different distribution of colors and styles, you can take a *weighted* average of the conditional revenues based on those distributions. This method is related to [indirect standardization](https://www.statsdirect.com/help/rates/smr.htm).